# pptxgenjs: This expression is not constructable

Tags: node.js, typescript, pptxgenjs

I am new to NodeJS.

I'm trying to write the following code for a NodeJS application (in `src/index.ts`):

```js
import pptxgenjs from 'pptxgenjs';
const pres = new pptxgenjs();
```

[Source](https://gitbrent.github.io/PptxGenJS/docs/usage-pres-create/)

But the Typescript compiler gives me the following error:

> This expression is not constructable.
> Type 'typeof import("########/node_modules/pptxgenjs/types/index")' has no construct signatures.

My `tsconfig.json` looks like this:

```json
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "NodeNext",
        "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
        "target": "ES2020",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "esModuleInterop": true,
        "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
    },
    "include": ["src/**/*"]
}
```

**What can I do to resolve this?**

Comment: Looking at the exported types on the project, it appears this is not an issue with your configuration but with the library: https://github.com/gitbrent/PptxGenJS/issues/1289. It does not provide a type for the constructor call.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts Can I create my own constructor declaration?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I am using the exact same code on a typescript project and it works for me.

```
import pptxgen from "pptxgenjs";
let pres: pptxgen
pres = new pptxgen();
```

It is inside a NextJs typescript project.

Below is the beginning of my tsconfig.json file.
Hope this helps.

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "es2020",
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom"
    ],
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "incremental": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "plugins": [
      {
        "name": "next"
      }
    ]
  },
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).